# If $G$ is an Abelian group and contains cyclic subgroups of order 4 and 6, what other sizes of cyclic group G must contain?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, solution-verification, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

Let $G$ be an abelian group. Let $a,b \in G$ such that $|a|=4, |b|=6$. 
$(ab)^{24}=a^{24}b^{24}=e$, identity of G. Hence $|ab|$ can be $1,2,3,4,6,8,12,24$ 
If $|ab|=8$ then $(ab)^8=e\implies e=a^8b^8=b^2$, which is a contradiction and hence $|ab|\ne 8,4,2,1$ 
If $|ab|=6$ then as above, $a^2=e$, which is again a contradiction and hence $|ab|\ne 6,3$ 
Clearly, $(ab)^{24}=e$ but we also have $(ab)^{12}=e$ and hence $|ab|=12$ 
Therefore, by fundamental theorem, subgroups of cyclic group $\langle ab\rangle $ can be of order $1,2,3,4,6,12 \;$(all divisors of 12). 
Is my solution correct? Or do I have to eliminate some more numbers from $1,2,3,4,6,12$? If yes, then how should I proceed? Thanks for your time. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you did is good. Remain to be proven that none of the orders that you found can be eliminated.

Clearly $1, 2, 3, 4, 6$ can't be eliminated:

- Identity element is of order $1$.
- If $\vert a \vert =4$ then $\vert a^2 \vert = 2$.
- $a$ is of order $4$.
- If $\vert b \vert = 6$ then $\vert b^2 \vert =3$.
- $\vert b \vert$ is having $6$ as order.

Remains the question of the existence of an element of order $12$... which is the case of $a b^2$. Can you prove it?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. About the existence of an element of order 12, I was thinking that $ab$ itself will do. Although I have verified that $ab^2$ is indeed of order 12, I just wanted to know can I consider $ab$ instead of $ab^2$. I think I can because $G$ is not given to be cyclic. If $G$ were cyclic, there would be only one subgroup of order 12, which is not the case here. Am I right? Please help.

Comment: But not in this case. Since, $|a|=4, |b|=6$ so $(ab)^12=e$ and $(ab)^24=e$ and hence $|ab|\ne 24$?